# why the background Notiifcation wasn't displayed correctly via FCM Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, background, firebase-cloud-messaging, handle

I'm trying to display background notification via fcm in my flutter application. However, I don't know why the notification that I created wasn't dispaly but there's another one with the same values in firestore database displayed.
this is how I created the notification:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
  Future<void> registerBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    AppLogger.log("background", message.data);
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

    AppLogger.log(" --- bACKGROUND message received ---", "");
    AppLogger.log("Title", message.notification!.title);
    AppLogger.log("Body", message.notification!.body);
    final String payload = message.data['version'];

    String smallIcon = 'drawable/small_launcher_icon';
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'channel_id',
              'channel_name',
              importance: Importance.max,
              priority: Priority.high,
              ticker: 'New message received',
              icon: smallIcon,
              playSound: true,
              enableVibration: true,
              largeIcon:
                  const DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('mipmap/launcher_icon'),
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 123, 255),
              ledColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
              ledOnMs: 1000,
              ongoing: true,
              ledOffMs: 500,
            ),
          ));
    }
    return Future.value();
  }
```

this is how I call it in main():

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  MessagingService _msgService = MessagingService();

  await _msgService.init();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_msgService.registerBackgroundMessage);
```

this is the init method in messagingService:

```
Future<void> init() async {
    await _requestPermission();
    _deviceId = await getDeviceId();

    AppLogger.log("DeviceId", _deviceId);

    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) async {
      AppLogger.log("FCM TOKEN", token);

      saveTokens(token!);
    });
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      print("FirebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage");
});
```

Ps: when I recieve the notification I got these errors in the cosole:
W/FLTFireMsgService(30433): A background message could not be handled in Dart as no onBackgroundMessage handler has been registered.
W/FirebaseMessaging(30433): Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created
by the app. Default value will be used.
this is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
             <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"


             android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

this is strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">fcm_default_channel</string>
</resources>
```

Thanks in advance for suggesting some solution to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive) states that there are requirements for the background message handler:

1. It must not be an anonymous function.
2. It must be a top-level function (e.g. not a class method which requires initialization).
3. When using Flutter version 3.3.0 or higher, the message handler must be annotated with `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` right above the function declaration (otherwise it may be removed during tree shaking for release mode).

This means that you cannot directly define the handler inside a class or method that requires initialization. Your function `registerBackgroundMessage` is not top-level function but method of `MessagingService` which has to be initialized. So, you have to make your background message handler top-level.

Comment: do you know how to send notification when app is killed ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please make change as per below code

 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(registerBackgroundMessage);

 Firebase background notification automatically generate from system 
 tray.we don't have to write any extra code for that.Please make sure 
 your payload is correct.

 For more information  [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive][1]
```

Comment: I didn't create extra code  ` @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  Future<void> registerBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
    print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
  }
` But even  this line wasn't get printed     print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}'); I don't know why I got this error Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest. Default value will be used

Comment: <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="your notification channel name" />    add this code in your manifest file in application section

Comment: now I got this problem A background message could not be handled in Dart as 
no onBackgroundMessage handler has been registered.

Comment: I already did this in one of my applications. Share your complete scenario and please make sure firebase messaging and local notifications version are latest